# Zeros when printing out an array which is declared on the heap. C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to make a program that lets the user insert some numbers to the array and the print it out afterwards. Problem is when I try to do that (lets say the size of my array is 100) then: 
What it should do: Inserted- `1,2,3,4,5` -> should print `1,2,3,4,5`
But instead it prints -> `1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0, ....` up to the size of my array. 
Is there any way I can get rid of those zeros? 
Code:

```
int SIZE = 100;
int main()
{
int *numbers;
numbers = new int[SIZE];
int numOfElements = 0;
int i = 0;
cout << "Insert some numbers (! to end): ";
while((numbers[i] != '!') && (i < SIZE)){
    cin >> numbers[i];
    numOfElements++;
    i++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < numOfElements; i++){
    cout << numbers[i] << " ";
}
delete [] numbers;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prefer using `std::vector` (or `std::array` where appropriate) over manually allocated arrays.

Comment: What are you trying to do here `numbers[i] != '!'` ?

Comment: You check the wrong array entry for `'!'`. Every entry gets checked befor you put the input in there leading to this condition being pretty useless. You should check the input in the loop and `break` if you get an input of `'!'`.

Comment: Good time to learn to use a debugger.  Here's a [read](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If you want `numbers[i] != '!'` to be false, the user needs to enter `33`, not `!`.

Answer (score 0):

Get `numOfElements` entered from user beforehand. For example

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int * a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cin >> a[i];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    delete[] a;
}
```

Input

```
4
10 20 30 40
```

Output

```
10 20 30 40
```

Answer (score 0):

You increase `numOfElements` no matter what the user types. Simply do this instead:

```
if(isdigit(numbers[i]))
{
  numOfElements++;
}
```

This will count digits, not characters. It may of course still be too crude if you want the user to input numbers with multiple digits.

Comment: But this does not end the loop, does it? You should add an `else break;`

Comment: Also `numbers[i]` is an integer. Don't you have to check the input before writing it into an array?

Comment: @jotasi Apparently the OP reads input as characters but like to store them in integers. I suppose there might be too many errors in the code to salvage it.

Comment: That might be true... Guess this question should be closed/deleted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared array size, all indices will be zeros.
User input changes only the first x indices from zero to the value entered (left to right).
All other indices remains 0.
If you want to output only integers different from 0 (user input) you can do something like that:

```
for(auto x : numbers){
if(x!=0)cout<<x<<" ";
}
```

You can use vector and push_back the values from user input to get exactly the
size you need without zeros, then you can use this simple code:

```
for(auto x : vectorName)cout<<x<<" ";
```

Comment: why indexes? maybe int or values.

Comment: index = position in array

Answer (score 0):

Previous solutions using a counter is fine.
otherwise you can (in a while... or similar)

1. read values in a "temp" var
2. add if temp non zero
3. exit loop if counter >= SIZE-1 (you reach max slots)
4. increment counter

when You will print, form 0 to counter, you will get only non zero values.